# Excel if List Contains Return Cell

Tags: excel

In Excel I have 10 different columns that contain `M` for Monday, `T` for Tuesday, etc. On a separate sheet I am making a calendar and would like to look through all columns and if that day is present, return the cells header (`$A$1`, `$B$1`, etc).

I can do this for a single column:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("W",'List'!C2)),'List'!$C$1,"")
```

But how do I either add multiple ifs (not nested), or pull the cell from a list if it is found? Like so:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("W",'List'!C1:C10)),Cell location from List Page,"")
```

Here is a screenshot of the table I'm working from:
[image]

Ideally, this would be the desired output:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of `List` sheet? It isn't clear what does `C1:C10` contain, and what do you want the formula to return.

Comment: I am still not sure about what the desired output would be and where it would go

Comment: With the given sample `=INDEX(B1:E1,MATCH("*W*",B2:E2,0))` will return `Math` (same for `M` and `F`), `Science` for `R`, but I'm not sure if that's what you need, and if a single letter can appear in only one column.

Comment: My apologies. I just added a new screen shot.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now

Comment: It looks like the index(B1...is almost exactly what I need! Is there a way to concatenate the return if there's a match? And how do I return multiple columns? Say math and science are both on Monday.

Comment: Well match will only return one value.  So there won't be anything to concatenate... an ArrayFormula is probably needed

Comment: If you want to concatenate it with `A2` simply use `=A2 & " " & INDEX(...)`, if you want to concatenate results for different matches (when one letter appears in more columns), then it's probably not easy to achieve without VBA.

Comment: Ok, looks like I'm gonna have to go the VBA route. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Well not easy does not equal not possible, im gonna play around a bit

Comment: I will have to agree.  Can't do it inside a single cell.  It is possible to make a list (multiple rows) of classes for that person though....

Answer (score 0):

`=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(FLATTEN(IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("M",B2:D),A2:A&" - "&B$1:$D$1,""))),FLATTEN(IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("M",B2:D),A2:A&" - "&B$1:$D$1,"")))<>""))`

I stumbled over this looking for something else, here is a solution in Google sheets!

Link to have a look
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eN0bMO6Fr6fMkpk592bHa69U3iBcGLhV1l4bix74640/edit?usp=sharing